# Criar formulario de radiobuttons

Tags: php, html

Eu estou a fazer uma plataforma de testes. E nessa plataforma, tenho na base de dados uma tabela das perguntas que contém

> idpergunta, textoPergunta, RespostaCerta

e a tabela alunos_teste que contém

> idResposta, Resposta, idPergunta, idTeste, IdAluno

E gostaria de saber como posso para cada pergunta demonstrar respostas diferentes. ou seja

Pergunta 1 
Pão + agua ? 
R: 1
R: 2
R: 3

Pergunta 2
Leite + azeite ? 
R: 1
R: 2
R: 3

Se alguém pudesse ajudar, ou tirar do seu tempo e falar comigo via skype ficava muito agradecido !

Answer (score 1):

Bom amigo, a sua pergunta esta um pouco incompleta, bem como o seu banco de dados.

Eu não consegui entender bem se o seu problema esta em relacionar e obter opções para as perguntas ou em puxá-las do seu banco de dados, no entanto a estrutura que você apresentou não parece atender ao que precisa:

Você possui apenas 2 tabelas, uma que contém não só as perguntas, mas suas resposta, em string imagino. E uma para registrar as respostas, ou testes, realizados pelo usuários. No entanto você deseja apresenta múltiplas respostas ou opções para cada pergunta, contendo apenas uma correta imagino. Porém não é possível você criar opções aleatoriamente, não de forma coerente, para suas perguntas. Comumente estruturas de múltiplas escolhas tem suas opções previamente criadas, o que torna mais coerente as opções e até torna a pergunta em questão mais complexa.

Para atender ao que precisa existe maneiras bem fáceis, uma delas você precisaria apenas criar mais 1 campo em sua tabela de perguntas, onde armazenaria 3 opções para a pergunta em questão e modificar o campo 'RespostaCerta' para armazenar a resposta correta. Ou poderia separar as perguntas das resposta, e criar uma tabela com as resposta, e relaciona-las por id ou qualquer outra forma.

No entanto se o seu problema está em obter informações do banco de dados, este exemplo de código pode lhe ajudar:

```
if (!$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')):
    echo 'Não foi possível conectar ao mysql';
    exit;
endif;

if (!mysql_select_db('mysql_dbname', $link)):
    echo 'Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados';
    exit;
endif;

$perguntaid = 1; //Neste exemplo, iremos obter respostas de uma única pergunta
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM `perguntas` WHERE `idpergunta`="'.$perguntaid.'"';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result):
    echo "Erro do banco de dados, não foi possível consultar o banco de dados\n";
    echo 'Erro MySQL: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
endif;

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$respostacerta = $row['RespostaCerta'];
/*Caso siga minha sugestão de criar um campo com opções, e este campo seja uma string separando as opções por vírgula*/
$opcoes = $row['opcoes'];
$opcoes = explode(',', $opcoes);//separa as opções por vírgula
echo $row ['textoPergunta'];
foreach($opcoes as $opcao):
    echo $opcao;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Caso não seja esta a solução que procura, tente detalhar melhor a sua pergunta e procurar evidenciar onde esta realmente o seu problema

Comment: Eu já consigo listar as minhas perguntas, agora o problema apenas é listar respostas em formularios diferentes, de modo a que se responder a 2ª questão, nao "deselecione" o que estva selecionado na 1ª questão

Comment: em formulários diferentes?
Bom, se uma input está interferindo nas inputs de outras perguntas, provavelmente você está usando a mesma name para todas, veja este exemplo com 2 perguntas https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/bam38ocp/

Comment: é exatamente isso, eu adicionei na base de dados, as respostas erradas. agora gostaria de saber como as puder listar em formulários diferentes para cada questão, ou seja atribuir nomes dinâmicos para cada resposta diferente

Comment: Não ficou muito claro quanto a maneira que você utilizou para armazenar as opções de cada pergunta, se é dentro da tabela `perguntas` ou dentro de `alunos_testes`. Caso as suas respostas estejam dentro da tabela `alunos_testes`, separadas das perguntas, você pode listá-las por uma chamada mysql, selecionando todas as respostas para uma determinada `idPergunta`

Comment: Para que todas as perguntas tenham opções independentes das outras perguntas, você precisa atribuir nomes diferentes para as inputs. Como no exemplo que fiz, cada pergunta apresenta 3 inputs com suas names iguais para as opções, mas diferentes entre as perguntas

Comment: Sim, mas eu estou a retirar as respostas da base de dados, e não tenho como alterar manualmente